# How to change a QImage that is already set up and shown within QWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I want to change an image with my mouse. So, everytime I click somewhere, the image should change.  I can show an image only one time. So I need to separate the initialization of everything that is needed to show an image from the part of code that is responsable for building an image.

Here is what I have got by far

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Example(QWidget):



    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.gx=1
        self.gy=1
        self.tlb=QLabel()
        self.lbl=QLabel()
        self.image = QImage(512, 512, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.initUI()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        px = QMouseEvent.pos().x()
        py = QMouseEvent.pos().y()

        size = self.frameSize()

        self.gx = px-size.width()/2
        self.gy = py-size.height()/2

        self.fillImage()


    def initUI(self):    
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()

        size = self.frameSize()

        self.fillImage()

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')

        self.tlb = QLabel(str(self.gx)+" : "+str(self.gy), self)
        self.tlb.move(12,3)
        self.show()  

    def fillImage(self):
        for x in range(0, 512):
            t = -1+(x/512)*2
            color =  (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t))*t**2) 

            for y in range(0, 512):

                t1 = -1+(y/512)*2
                color1 = (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t1))*t1**2)
                result = (255/2)+(color * color1 * (t*self.gx+t1*self.gy) )*(255/2)

                self.image.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(result, result, result))

        self.pixmap = self.pixmap.fromImage(self.image)

        self.tlb = QLabel(str(self.gx)+" : "+str(self.gy), self)

        print(self.gx)

        self.update()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `print(self.gx)` shows me that `self.gx` is changed, but the image isn't changed at all.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell the GUI that it needs to refresh the image.

In QT it seems you will need to call the `update()` or `repaint()` methods of the widget.

Comment: i've already tried to call self.repaint() and/or self.update() at the end of fill Image function, but it didn't help

Comment: It helped mine.
@pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.repaint()
        self.update()

Answer (score 1):

I've added `self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)` into `fillImage` before `self.repaint()` and `self.update()` and now it works, then i changed a little the code and now it looks like this

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.gx=1
        self.gy=1
        self.lbl=QLabel()
        self.tlb = None
        self.image = QImage(512, 512, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.length = 1
        self.initUI()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        px = QMouseEvent.pos().x()
        py = QMouseEvent.pos().y()

        size = self.frameSize()

        self.gx = px-size.width()/2
        self.gy = py-size.height()/2

        h = (self.gx**2+self.gy**2)**0.5

        self.gx/=h
        self.gy/=h

        self.gx*=self.length
        self.gy*=self.length

        self.fillImage()

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        self.length+=(event.delta()*0.001)
        print(self.length)


    def initUI(self):    
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')

        self.addedWidget = None

        self.fillImage()

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.show()  

    def fillImage(self):
        for x in range(0, 512):
            t = -1+(x/512)*2
            color =  (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t))*t**2) 

            for y in range(0, 512):

                t1 = -1+(y/512)*2
                color1 = (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t1))*t1**2)
                result = (255/2)+(color * color1 * (t*self.gx+t1*self.gy) )*(255/2)

                self.image.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(result, result, result))


        self.pixmap = self.pixmap.fromImage(self.image)

        if self.lbl == None:
            self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        else:
            self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        if self.addedWidget == None:
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
            self.addedWidget = True

        if self.tlb==None:
            self.tlb = QLabel(str(self.gx)+" : "+str(self.gy), self)
            self.tlb.move(12,3)
        else:
            self.tlb.setText(str(self.gx)+" : "+str(self.gy))

        self.repaint()
        self.update()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```